# how can I retrieve a reference to this in a promise.then ()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise

javascript / Node.js

how can I retrieve a reference to this/object inside a promise.then  ?

```
var controller = new MyController(params);

controller.action_send();

/////////////////////////////////

class MyController{

    constructor(params)
    {
        this.params = params;
    }

    action_send()
    {
        var promise = ext_lib.send();


        promise.then(
            function(details) {

                this.action_save(details);
                //(node:27014) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'action_save' of undefined
           });
   }

    action_save(details)
    {  
     save (this.params, details);
    }   
}
```

a PHPStorm warning says
Warns against a common mistake of trying to reference a member of an ECMAScript class via this. 
qualifier in a nested function that is not a lambda. 
this in a nested function that is not a lambda is the function's own 'this' and doesn't relate to the outer class.

tks from now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an arrow function.

Unlike a regular function, an arrow function does not bind `this`. Instead, this is bound lexically (i.e. this keeps its meaning from its original context).

Here are more details about it [Arrow Functions](https://codeburst.io/javascript-arrow-functions-for-beginners-926947fc0cdc)

Answer (score 2):

You want to use an arrow function: `(details) => {...}`.  This will make the scope the same as outside of the function, and so `this` should be your class.

I would also recommend looking up the difference between the `function` syntax and the `=>` syntax, someone can probably explain it better than I.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to the above answers, this is how your code should look like

```
promise()
.then(function (results) {
  }.bind(this)
).catch(...);
```

Make sure your bind is just before closing ***then()***