# How do I assign a axios put request's response to variables

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to assign a value from my axios' response to a variable. How do I assign ContactID to a variable to use further?

my axios response:

`{"0":{"Type":"ACCREC","Contact":{"ContactID":"b612f859-b9ea-4b98-a888-f0a666f859d4","AccountNumber":"TestingSylvester","ContactStatus":"ACTIVE","Name":"Testing }}}`

my axios request:

```
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
  this.axiosResponse.push(JSON.stringify(response.data));

})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

I tried this, but I get the error: "Cannot read property 'axiosResponse' of undefined"

Comment: Most likely `this` is not bound, which would explain the error message you are getting. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51805334/how-can-i-retrieve-a-reference-to-this-in-a-promise-then

Comment: @mynd you were correct. An arrow function immediately solved my issue, thanks!

Comment: I've added my comment as answer. Would be nice if you could accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely `this` is not bound, which would explain the error message you are getting. Check [how can I retrieve a reference to this in a promise.then ()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51805334/how-can-i-retrieve-a-reference-to-this-in-a-promise-then)

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined `axiosResponse` anywhere. All you have declared is the function parameter named `response`. hence you get the error  message you described.

Comment: @FrankPI   It has been declared under my data function as  `axiosResponse: [ ] ,`